# Python multiprocessing MUCH slower than sequential

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

To start out with, I know there are about 20 questions with similar titles, and I promise I've read all of them.

I know about most of the drawbacks of Python multiprocessing, and I wasn't expecting a *massive* speedup from applying it. This is my first time using `multiprocessing.Process`, in the past I've always used a `Pool`. I think I'm doing something wrong with it, because it is running several orders of magnitude slower. One iteration of the sequential method is running in less than a second, whereas one iteration of the parallel method is taking well more than a minute.

For context, this is an n-body simulator, and this particular method is checking for collisions and updating forces acting on each body. I know there are better ways to do this, this is just for my learning.

Here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager


def par_run_helper(self, part, destroy, add):
    for other in self.parts:
        if other not in destroy and other is not part:
            if part.touches(other):
                add.append(part + other)
                destroy.append(other)
                destroy.append(part)
                self.touches += 1
                print("TOUCH " + str(part.size + other.size))
            else:
                part.interact(other, self.g)

def par_run(self, numTicks=1, visualizeEvery=1, visualizeAfter=0):
    manager = Manager()
    destroy = manager.list()
    add = manager.list()
    for tick in range(numTicks):
        print(tick)
        processes = []
        for part in self.parts:
            print(part)
            p = Process(target=self.par_run_helper, args=(part, destroy, add))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        for p in destroy:
            try:
                self.parts.remove(p)
            except Exception:
                pass
        for p in add:
            self.parts.append(p)
```

Each iteration should take approximately the same amount of time, as they're all operating on the same number of elements.

Manager is `multiprocessing.Manager()`.
`part` is short for particle and is the particle I am currently updating.
`destroy` and `add` are lists of particles that will be destroyed and added at the end of the tick.
I tested with only 300 parts, but I'd like to be able to do as many as 1000.

Comment: Need more detail on what `part`, `destroy`, `Manager` etc are. How many `parts` are there?

Comment: The reason that I ask is that `subprocess` uses `pickle` to pass the data from the parent process to the subprocesses. If you have a lot of parts and/or they're large objects, there will be a (significant) serialisation overhead for the parent process and similarly a deserialisation overhead in each subprocess.

Comment: Hi @bendl, could you pelase share a couple of more details?, which `import` are you doing? where is this being run(CPU info...)? sequential code you said it un faster?, Which SO? Python version you are running?. Usually creating processes is a cpu-consuming task.

Comment: Tom already pointed out the pickle issue.  Another possibility is locking. You are apparently using aggressively your add and destroy lists in loops. When you do that, Manager() uses locking for consistency.  Could you instead have temporary local add and destroy lists in workers and append to those, and only when a worker loop is complete, copy data from the local variables to the Manager lists?

Comment: `add` and `destroy` are only appended to if there happens to be a collision between `part`s, which is sufficiently rare that the overhead from using them should be small

Comment: @TomDalton that's for regular objects as well? ie ones not created by `Manager`?

Comment: Sorry, I originally missed where Manager was coming from. I'm pretty sure the shared lists (e.g. manager.list) don't have a significant serdes overhead, and it sounds from above like the RPC/locking overhead is small too. So my focus would be on 1. what `part` looks like and how big it's pickle representation is? 2. How many `parts` (subprocesses) are there?

Comment: Also, both your methods take `self` but I don't see the surrounding class definition? Whatever `self` is probably also be getting [de]serialised so that the instance method with correct state... and `self` seems to contain all `.parts`... you can see where I'm going with this.

Comment: @TomDalton I added some more info at the end of my post. I'm using about 300 parts right now, but that number falls as there are more collisions. Parts aren't huge, but they're also not tiny. They contain 3 floats and two instances of a custom class that contains 2 floats. Could the custom class be causing issues?

Comment: @TomDalton I do... Is there a good way to get around this? `self.parts` will remain static for the entire time it is being accessed.

Comment: What does `len(pickle.dumps(part))` looks like (and how long does it take), and the same question for `len(pickle.dumps(self))`?

Comment: @TomDalton `len(pickle.dumps(part))=206` and `len(pickle.dumps(self))=36568` `Self` seems to be gradually increasing in size, but nothing dramatic. They are both quite fast... I can try a timeit maybe if needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157490/discussion-between-tom-dalton-and-bendl).

Comment: After some more investigation, it seems that the significant slowdown is on the line `p.start()`

Comment: This is missing too much code to tell what's going on, but it looks like every thread is using the same central data store. It may very well be you are expending a lot of power to make sure only one thread can do anything at a time, and a lot more power determining which thread gets to do something.